# Collecting values from a Python dictionary with list of keys

Tags: python, function, dictionary, key

```
Dict = {'w1': 56, 'w2': 19, 'w3': 77, 'w4': 45, 'w5': 31}
myWords = ['w1','w4','w5']

OutputList=[]
for items in myWords:
    tmps = Dict[items]
    OutputList.append(tmps)
```

My question is can we, *without* using **`for` loop**, collect the values (output) from a dictionary with a particular list ("myWord")?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using a for-loop?

Comment: **Do not** use variables with an upper case name! **Do not** reuse the name of built-ins with only a changed capitalization!

Comment: Not sure *how* you managed it, but it looks like you uncovered a bug. You cannot normally mark more than one answer as 'accepted' (you are supposed to pick the one that helped you the most). Yet here we are, with two answers marked as accepted.. See [How did this question get two accepted answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294342)

Answer (score 19):

This is what [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) is for:

```
>>> import operator
>>> Dict = {'w1': 56, 'w2': 19, 'w3': 77, 'w4': 45, 'w5': 31}
>>> myWords = ['w1','w4','w5']
>>> operator.itemgetter(*myWords)(Dict)
(56, 45, 31)
```

Comment: Hi, Chepner If the dict is large said len(Dict.keys()) = 1048576, and my list about 10000, so the  operator.itemgetter can improve the performance when compare to For loop ?

Comment: You would have to test it, but I imagine `itemgetter` should be faster.

Comment: Hey chepner, nice answer. However a small suggestion .. Do add a link to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as it will really help those who don't know about `operator.itemgetter`

Comment: Good suggestion. I've added a link to the Python 2 docs; I don't think there are any differences in the [Python 3 version](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Comment: @chepner Did you really have a list result, like shown in the code? I thought itemgetter returns a tuple.

Comment: Who knows what I was thinking in 2015? Yes, it should be a tuple :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use a *list comprehension*:

```
OutputList = [Dict[x] for x in myWords]
```

Comment: Is a (```for```) loop implicit in a comprehension?

Comment: yes, either way you have to loop over the list, in Python if possible it's better to use map and the builtin functions when iterating, because those are implemented in C

Comment: @wwii: Just because the list comprehension syntax includes the keyword `for`, doesn't mean it is a "for loop".

Comment: @Javier sometimes comprehensions are more efficient than using ```map``` and the other builtins.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries): ```The comprehension consists of a single expression followed by at least one for clause and zero or more for or if clauses.```.  The word ```for``` in that statement links to the ```for``` statement in the docs.

Comment: Hi, Greg. If the dict is large said len(Dict.keys()) = 1048576, and my list about 10000,then is " [Dict[x] for x in myWords] " better than using map ?

Comment: @wwii: That seems like a really misleading link, because the `for` keyword as used in the list comprehension syntax bears only a superficial resemblance to the `for` statement.

Comment: @ChinLim: The relative performance of the two options depends on your environment and data. I suggest you measure the performance of each to determine which is fastest on your system.

Comment: Just curious, I see a lot of comprehension answers to for loop averse questions and it just seems like a comprehension is a for loop, although there can be performance differences.

Answer (score 5):

Here are benchmarks of several different methods:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import timeit
from operator import itemgetter

def f1(d, l):
    '''map'''
    return list(map(d.get, l))

def f2(d, l):
    '''itemgetter'''
    return itemgetter(*l)(d)

def f3(d, l):
    '''list comprehension'''
    return [d[k] for k in l]

def f4(d, l):
    '''WRONG, but map and filter'''
    return list(map(lambda k: d[k], filter(d.get, l)))

def f5(d, l):
    '''simple for loop'''
    rtr=[]
    for e in l:
        rtr.append(d[e])
    return rtr  

def f6(d, l):
    '''CORRECTED map, filter '''    
    return list(map(lambda k: d[k], filter(d.__contains__, l))) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s=10000000
    d={'W{}'.format(k):k for k in range(s)} 
    l=['W{}'.format(x) for x in range(0,s,4)]

    times=[]                
    for f in (f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6):
        times.append((f.__doc__, timeit.timeit('f(d,l)', setup="from __main__ import f, d, l", number=10)))

    for e in sorted(times, key=itemgetter(1)):
         print('{:30}{:10.3f} seconds'.format(*e))
```

For Python 2.7, prints:

```
itemgetter                         4.109 seconds
list comprehension                 4.467 seconds
map                                5.450 seconds
simple for loop                    6.132 seconds
CORRECTED map, filter             11.283 seconds
WRONG, but map and filter         11.852 seconds
```

Python 3.4:

```
itemgetter                         5.196 seconds
list comprehension                 5.224 seconds
map                                5.923 seconds
simple for loop                    6.548 seconds
WRONG, but map and filter          9.080 seconds
CORRECTED map, filter              9.931 seconds
```

PyPy:

```
list comprehension                 4.450 seconds
map                                4.718 seconds
simple for loop                    5.962 seconds
itemgetter                         7.952 seconds
WRONG, but map and filter          8.962 seconds
CORRECTED map, filter              9.909 seconds
```

You can see that even with a dictionary of similar size (1,000,000 elements) to what the OP states, that a simple 'for' loop is competitive with fancier methods. A list comprehension is very competitive.

You can also see that something that looks fancy is not that great.

*premature optimization is the root of all evil*

Comment: Interesting that `itemgetter` is actually *worse* in PyPy, rather than just being less optimized.

Answer (score 4):

or to use map, if `myWords` contains keys the dictionary `Dict`, to use

```
OutputList = map(Dict.get, myWords)
```

Comment: Hi, Jose. If the dict is large said  len(Dict.keys()) = 1048576, and my list about 10000, so the map function can improve the performance when compare to For loop ?

Comment: @GregHewgill can you help me with this question, because I do not know

Comment: @ChinLim, try it and see - [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)

Comment: this approach will include None in the OutputList if the element is not contained in the dictionary

Comment: @Javier, yes .... you are right, add `None` .... is better chepner's solution in this case

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
d = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2}
result = map(lambda x: d[x], filter(d.get, l))
print result #[1, 2]
```

Comment: Hi Javier. Thanks.  What the "lamda x: d[x]" do in above example? In python help file the  map (function, sequence) , is this suggestion can work on huge dictionary and large list.. Thanjs

Comment: could you explain why the vote down? This answer the question, with a different approach

Comment: You're trying to obtain the values of the dictionary, Map will loop over the result of Filter, and will return a list with the first parameter (the lambda function) applied for every element resulted in filter.
Try it in a Python shell, this will yield what you're expecting

Comment: Hi, Javier.. Ur answer is useful.. May i know the vote down refer to ? Thanks.

Comment: This actually does not work. If you have any value in the dict d that is not truth, it will be filtered out by filter since 'get' is returning the value.

Comment: Try `d={'a':0, 'b':0}; filter(d.get, ['a', 'b'])` which returns an empty list.

Comment: you may use `d.has_key` instead of `d.get` in filter

Comment: Even using `d.has_key`, you will still do *two* dictionary lookups per key.

Comment: True, I honestly oversaw the False value in the dict and get. Thanks much for the clarification!